# RoR: Associated two existing models via has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: `ModelA`, `ModelB`, related though `has_and_belongs_to_many` in both.

Usually, I'd do:

> modela.modelbs.create(params)

, but both the models already exist. So, how can I create the relationship in a many-to-many join table (attributes: `modela_id`, `modelb_id`)?

Essentially giving the SQL: `INSERT INGORE INTO join_table (id1, id2);` (`IGNORE` is important here as I have a unique index on `(modela_id, modelb_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what I set out and avoid extra logic and database queries, https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import works brilliantly and with `:ignore => true` provides `INSERT INGORE`

Answer (score 1):

```
modela.modelbs << modelb
```

See the has_and_belongs_to_many api docs for more info.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if this can be modified to ensure INSERT IGNORE?

Comment: @Ashley I don't know.  There is a :uniq => true option you can apply to the HABTM association which may help with that.